# How to get selected value from select2 in vue js 2.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, vuejs2

I guess title is pretty straightforward. This is my `select2` in `vuejs`

```
<select multiple id="roles" class="form-control" v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="role in roles" :value="role.id">{{role.name}}</option>
</select>
```

The `v-model="selected"` is not updating when I am using select2 but works fine when I do not initialize `select2`, i.e. use simple `multiselect`.

Answer (score 0):

[v-model.lazy](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy) may do the trick here. Try following:

```
<select multiple id="roles" class="form-control" v-model.lazy="selected">
```